# Stop <video> on mobile device opening native player

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html5-video

How can I stop a `<video>` with autoplay set from opening in the native device player after load?

In a React component I add the video by

```
return (
  <video style={{objectFit: 'cover', width: '100%', height: '80vh'}} id="background-video" loop muted autoPlay>
     <source src={this.state.videoURL} type="video/mp4" />
     <source src={this.state.videoURL} type="video/ogg" />
  </video>
)
```

Video src is defined as

```
this.state = {
    videoURL: '//videos.ctfassets.net/1lmibopww0w9/5U4jOdHuRq62cygeyokaW6/f5444869997a7297f19ea847ccb16ae9/Black_Sands.mp4'
}
```

The video loads as intended on **desktop browsers** and sits with the webpage. Yet, on **mobile browsers** the video loads in the browser before opening in fullscreen in the native player.

How can I define the video to play on mobile devices with opening in native player?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

iOS and Android have policies for inline videos.

In both cases they only allow autoplay videos that have no audio track or are muted.

I would add `muted`, `autoPlay` and `playsinline` attributes to the `video` tag.

More info:

- New video policies for iOS: https://webkit.org/blog/6784/new-video-policies-for-ios/
- Muted autoplay in Android: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/07/autoplay
- `video` attributes in MDN (see `playsinline`): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video

Comment: Thank you. One thing for those adding to **React** `playsinline` is `playsInline`.